# Embedding javascript object in dynamically created html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a js function that recieves an array of items. The function itself creates html content dynamicly using a call to jquery html function. The problem is that I don't remember how to embed correctly the array inside the appended html. For example,

```
var ErrorsNotifier = {
   init: function(items) {
        var template = '<div id="message">'; 
        template += '<div id="id">some message.<br /><br />'; 
        template += '<div class="errorsList">error desc</div></div>'; 
        template += '<a href="#" class="goback" onclick="ErrorsNotifier.Back("+items+");"></a>'; 
        template += '<a href="#" class="proceed" onclick="ErrorsNotifier.Next();"></a>'; 
        template += '<input type="image" src="someimage" alt="" class="" onclick="window.open("someurl");"/></div>'; 
        $("#content").html(template);
   }
}
```

After the html will be rendered to the body, clicking on the anchor tag return the following error - `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

inspecting the anchor tag in the browser will show the following

```
a href="#" class="goback" onclick="ErrorsNotifier.Back([object Object]);"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var ErrorsNotifier = {
   init: function(items) {
       ...
       var $template = $(template);
       $template.find('a.goback').on('click', function(){ErrorsNotifier.Back(items);});
       $("#content").empty().append($template);
   }
}
```

notice I used `.on()` to attach the event handler.

Comment: Thanks Musa, I'll try it but why not using the html function instead of empty the content element and then append to it ?

Comment: I tried your sln and it didn't work maybe I should have mentioned that the template contains other html element and I concatenate them to each other.

Comment: var template = '<div id="message">';
template += '<div id="id">some message.<br /><br />';
template += '<div class="errorsList">error desc</div></div>';
template += '<a href="#" class="goback" onclick="ErrorsNotifier.Back("+items+");"></a>';
template += '<a href="#" class="proceed" onclick="ErrorsNotifier.Next();"></a>';
template += '<input type="image" src="someimage" alt="" class=""  onclick="window.open("someurl");"/></div>';
$("#content").html(template);

Answer (score 0):

```
var ErrorsNotifier = {
 init: function(items) {
    var template = '<a href="#" class="goback" onclick="ErrorsNotifier.Back(\''+items+'\');">Link</a>';
    $("#content").html(template);
   },
 Back: function(x){ alert(x); }
};
```

Check this

Comment: That pretty much the same thing the OP is doing.

Comment: doesn't do the trick just wrapp the array object with single qutation marks